# "Grouping" several async_work_group_copy() calls with a single event

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, opencl, gpgpu

Am I right, that the following quote from the OpenCL 1.1 standard (section **6.11.10**)

> The event argument can also be used to associate the
>   async_work_group_copy with a previous async copy **allowing an event to
>   be shared by multiple async copies**;

means I could "group" several `async_work_group_copy()` calls with a single event and **use only that event to wait for the whole group** of copying operations to complete?


**Remark**: Seems, the code snippet for the `using_local()` kernel in the following blogpost do exactly that?
https://streamcomputing.eu/blog/2014-06-19/using-async_work_group_copy-on-2d-data/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On an Intel iGPU,

```
// tmp-store
// tmp2-compute
// tmp3-load    
pipelineEvent[0]=async_work_group_copy(&b[g*gs],tmp,gs,pipelineEvent[0]);
pipelineEvent[0]=async_work_group_copy(tmp3,&e[g*gs],gs,pipelineEvent[0]);
tmp2[l]=tmp2[l]+3;
wait_group_events(1,&pipelineEvent[0]);
```

gives same output with same latency as

```
// tmp-store
// tmp2-compute
// tmp3-load    
pipelineEvent[0]=async_work_group_copy(&b[g*gs],tmp,gs,0);
pipelineEvent[1]=async_work_group_copy(tmp3,&e[g*gs],gs,0);
tmp2[l]=tmp2[l]+3;
wait_group_events(2,&pipelineEvent[0]);
```

so the spec must be right about "shared by multiple async copies".

---

Maybe `event_t` has a counter inside. Then maybe

- `async_work_group_copy` increments it by 1(or by N=number of workitems per group)
- when async complete, scheduler decrements counter by 1 (or each workitem decrements by 1)
- `wait_group_events` checks if it is zero

so it doesn't matter if one uses 90 events or single event (and doesn't speculate more) .

---

But if one approaches the "can also be used to associate" part in tha spec **speculatively**,

if an implementation just **interleaves** instructions to do the "async":

```
multiple events for multiple async copies
copy1 calculate copy2 calculate copy1 calculate copy2 calculate copy1

single event for multiple async copies(grouped copies)
copy1 copy2 calculate copy1 copy2 calculate copy1 copy2 calculate
```

waiting barrier could be finer grained when copies are grouped and checked(against completion) once instead of twice at each async iteration.

if implementation does the copying **concurrently asynchronous**(such as using scalar pipelines for copies while using SIMD pipelines for compute, NCU for example having 2xScalar units and 30xSIMD units in each compute unit):

```
multiple events for multiple copies
SIMD: compute compute compute compute
scalar-1: copy1 copy1 copy1 copy1
scalar-2: copy2 copy2 copy2 copy2

single event for multiple copies
SIMD: compute compute compute compute
scalar-1:copy1 copy2 copy1 copy2 copy1 copy2
scalar-2: copy1 copy2 copy1 copy2 copy1 copy2
```

then the multiple event version could be faster since reads and writes are independently done on different pipelines.

---

CPU,GPU, FPGA can work totally different and `async_work_group_copy` is supported to stop us speculating on coalesced memory accesses using primitives(or their vector types) so I'd use any version of event handling that seems useful.